# can i use perl to download files in a php script?

Tags: php, perl

i have a file sharing website made in php which gives users to download files.But as i am using a hosted server there is limitation on time out and other factors that come to play while for a download script coded in php. This causes large files to get corrupted while downloading. i am looking for a solution for this i have tried using symbolic links but the force download factor is not taking place....

i am thinking of using perl to download files bt dont have any clue what so ever....

can any one help me outwith this problem???

Comment: I suppose that on perl scripts there is no limits, otherwise - what you Gain from the exchange?
if so, dont use perl in PHP, but perl instead of PHP. mean, give all the downloading jobs to PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rough Perl script which makes use of the CGI module. It has been written to demonstrate core concepts and is not production ready.

It assumes:

- You will invoke via URL, directly or iFrame etc.
- You will pass the parameter filename. Its value is the filename of the file you want to download.
- The dirpath where the files live is the current working directory.
- The path seperator is / (Linux).

Fundamentally, printing the appropriate content type will force the download to disk.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => qw(all);
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI;
use Cwd;

my $cgi = CGI->new;

my $dirpath  = getcwd;
my $filename = $cgi->param('filename') || die 'filename required';
my $filepath = $dirpath . '/' . $filename;

open my $fh, '<', $filepath or die "cannot open '$filepath': $!";
my $filedata = do { $/ = undef; <$fh> };
close $fh;

print $cgi->header( -type       => 'application/octet-stream',
                    -attachment => $filename );

print $filedata;
```

Comment: how to call it from a php script???

Comment: It is an independent script that could be called from your PHP like `<iframe src="http://example.com/download.pl?filename=myfile.txt" width="0" height="0" />`. The code is unlikely to work how you want right out of the box...

Answer (score 0):

You can run bash command inside php scripts

```
<?php
    $command = "ls -lrat";
    Shell_exec($command);
```